Dell precision 3571: Onboard HDMI going through Intel instead of the NVIDIA RTX A2000
So, I have this laptop, and recently, I bought a Samsung G9. I am trying to use the G9 as the main display, and I'm getting the full resolution of 5K, but I see that the GFX card is Intel instead of Nvidia. The refresh rate is stuck at 60Hz, and none of Nvidia's enhancements are applied. Unity 3D and other tools are not behaving as if they are powered by RTX.


Now, generic help on the internet is BIOS but I have looked up the docs for the laptop already. From the main manual, I found the Multiple display support matrix (https://dl.dell.com/content/manual30934414-precision-3571-setup-and-specifications.pdf?language=en-us):

And from the Service Manual (https://dl.dell.com/content/manual23633064-precision-3571-service-manual.pdf?language=en-us), I went through all BIOS options and couldn't find the option to choose Nvidia over Intel.
How do I allow Nvidia to take over displays? I do not have the Dell dock.
